# How to pass a standard function as a parameter?

Tags: php

I would like to do something like this, but... working!

```
function _mathOperation($a, $b, $operation, $conversion)
{
    return $operation($conversion($a), $conversion($b));
}
echo _mathOperation(4,   5, function($a, $b) { return $a+$b; }, intval);
echo _mathOperation(4.6, 5, function($a, $b) { return $a+$b; }, floatval);
```

I have the problem with passing `intval` and `floatval` as function parameter.

How do you do handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing the quotes around the function names:

```
function _mathOperation($a, $b, $operation, $conversion)
{
    return $operation($conversion($a), $conversion($b));
}
echo _mathOperation(4,   5, function($a, $b) { return $a+$b; }, "intval");
//                                                             ^^      ^^
echo _mathOperation(4.6, 5, function($a, $b) { return $a+$b; }, "floatval");
//                                                             ^^        ^^
```

http://3v4l.org/AYiKN

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the conversion parameter as the function name, rather than trying to pass the function.

e.g.

```
<?php
echo _mathOperation(4,   5, function($a, $b) { return $a+$b; }, 'intval');
```